# Why the scope still gets cancelled even when I use SupervisorJob?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have a CoroutineScope where I pass a SupervisorJob and a CoroutineExceptionHandler. My coroutineScope has 2 child coroutines in it. However if one of the children fails, it leads to the scope cancellation, because the `Coroutine 2 is done...` message doesn't get printed. Why is that happen even if I use a SupervisorJob? In the case of a supervisorScope, it's fine.

```
fun main() = runBlocking {
val exceptionHandler = CoroutineExceptionHandler { coroutineContext, throwable ->
    println("Caught $throwable") // Works fine
}

val coroutineScope = CoroutineScope(SupervisorJob() + exceptionHandler)

val job1 = coroutineScope.launch {
    launch {
        println("Coroutine 1 is working...") // Prints
        delay(300L)
        throw Exception("Exception in coroutine 1")
    }

    launch {
        println("Coroutine 2 is working...") // Prints
        delay(500L)
        println("Coroutine 2 is done...") // Doesn't get printed
    }
}

job1.join()
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It leads to the scope cancellation

This is not true, because you can print `coroutineScope.isActive` and it will print `true`. You can also start another Child coroutine which is not cancelled even after `Exception` is thrown:

```kotlin
import kotlinx.coroutines.*

fun main() = runBlocking {
    val parentHandler = CoroutineExceptionHandler { _, throwable ->
        println("Parent caught $throwable")
    }

    val coroutineScope = CoroutineScope(SupervisorJob() + parentHandler)

    val job1 = coroutineScope.launch {
        launch {
            println("GrandChild_1 is working...")
            delay(300L)
            throw Exception("Exception in GrandChild_1")
        }

        launch {
            println("GrandChild_2 is working...")
            delay(500L)
            println("GrandChild_2 is done")
        }
    }

    val job2 = coroutineScope.launch {
        delay(1000L)
        println("Child_2 done")
    }

    job1.join()
    println("Child_1 active: ${job1.isActive}")
    job2.join()

    delay(1000)
    println("Parent still active: ${coroutineScope.isActive}")
}

// GrandChild_1 is working...
// GrandChild_2 is working...
// Parent caught java.lang.Exception: Exception in GrandChild_1
// Job1 active: false
// Child_2 done
// Parent still active: true
```

So what is happening?

> A failure or cancellation of a child does not cause the supervisor job to fail

Only failure of **immediate child** though, not grandchild. Because `job1 = coroutineScope.launch` creates a new `CoroutineScope` (referenced by `this` inside) and has its own `Job`, but its parent's job is `SupervisorJob`. So when it encounters some `Exception`, it is not propagated to parent because parent's job is `SupervisorJob`.

But when GrandChild_1 is launched using `launch` it creates new `CoroutineScope` again and has its own `Job`, and this time its parent's job is also `Job` (`job1` is its parent). So GrandChild_1's exception is propagated to parent and cancel's `job1`.

Root `val coroutineScope` is still active and `job2` is still not cancelled.

Answer (score 2):

When you call `launch`, there is one direct parent Job of the Job you are launching. In this code, the launched coroutine (`outerJob`) is a child of SupervisorJob:

```
val supervisorScope = CoroutineScope(SupervisorJob())

val outerJob = supervisorScope.launch {
  //...
}
```

But when you launch a coroutine from within another coroutine lambda like below, the inner coroutines are children of the outer coroutine's internal CoroutineScope, not the outer CoroutineScope that's using a SupervisorJob.

```
val outerJob = supervisorScope.launch { // Lambda's receiver is a new CoroutineScope that is
                                        // scoped to this launch block and this CoroutineScope's 
                                        // Job is outerJob. outerJob will be the parent Job of any
                                        // coroutines launched from this internal CoroutineScope.

  val innerJob = launch { // launch called on the internal (unnamed) CoroutineScope receiver, so 
                          // the parent Job of innerJob is outerJob, NOT the SupervisorJob.
    
  }

}
```

The supervising behavior does not cascade down to "grandchildren" of the SupervisorJob, only to its direct children. Cascading behavior would be very confusing and difficult to manage in coroutines that span different classes due to calling public suspend functions.

This is the default behavior for internal CoroutineScopes created by coroutine starting functions like `launch`, `async`, and `runBlocking`. If you want to change the behavior, you need to use `supervisorScope` to manually create another internal CoroutineScope that behaves like a supervisor.

Answer (score 1):

```
    val job1 = coroutineScope.launch() {
        println("Coroutine info $this")

        supervisorScope {
            println("Info inSide coroutineScope $this")
            launch() {
                println("Coroutine 1 is working...") // Prints
                delay(300L)
                throw Exception("Exception in coroutine 1")
            }

            launch {
                println("Coroutine 2 is working...") // Prints
                delay(500L)
                println("Coroutine 2 is done...") // Doesn't get printed
            }
        }

    }
```

The right way is use : supervisorScope.
You can see "println("Info inSide coroutineScope $this")" will print: Coroutine info StandaloneCoroutine. It means that scope is not a SupervisorCoroutine.

If you want to use the coroutineScope you create before:

```
    val coroutineScope = CoroutineScope(SupervisorJob() + exceptionHandler)
 coroutineScope.launch{
println("Coroutine 1 is working...") // Prints
                delay(300L)
                throw Exception("Exception in coroutine 1")}
coroutineScope.lanuch{
 println("Coroutine 2 is working...") // Prints
                delay(500L)
                println("Coroutine 2 is done...") // Doesn't get printed}
```

Comment: That's true, supervisorScope will solve the issue. But why SupervisorJob doesn't work in this case? I mean where does the SupervisorJob in `CoroutineScope(SupervisorJob() + exceptionHandler)` get lost?)) I heard that The SupervisorJob only works if it is the coroutine’s direct parent. But isn't this the case? E.g. if I will do `coroutineScope.launch` to times the SupervisorJob will work.

Comment: Yes.  inside the coroutineScope.launch() is standalone coroutine scope. Updated the answer for the case you want to use the coroutineScope you created before